# Создание своей темы Opencart

Tags: cms, opencart

После установки CMS Opencart доступна стандартная тема Default. Я хочу создать свою тему, пусть будет называться ThemeDark. Что мне надо для этого сделать? Версия Opencart 3.0

Answer (score 1):

Скопировать папку `catalog/view/theme/default`, назвать копию `ThemeDark` и поместить её рядом с `catalog/view/theme/default`. Далее очистить кеш магазина. Далее менять файлы twig в папке `ThemeDark` в соответствии с вашим дизайном.